# Naming a file when downloading with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I see that you can set where to download a file to through Webdriver, as follows:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

But, I was wondering if there is a similar way to give the file a name when it is downloaded? Preferably, probably not something that is associated with the profile, as I will be downloading ~6000 files through one browser instance, and do not want to have to reinitiate the driver for each download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if there is a pure Selenium handler for this, but here is what I have done when I needed to do something with the downloaded file.

1. Set a loop that polls your download directory for the latest file that does **not** have a `.part` extension (this indicates a partial download and would occasionally trip things up if not accounted for. Put a timer on this to ensure that you don't go into an infinite loop in the case of timeout/other error that causes the download not to complete. I used the output of the `ls -t <dirname>` command in Linux (my old code uses `commands`, which is deprecated so I won't show it here :) ) and got the first file by using

   ```
   # result = output of ls -t
   result = result.split('\n')[1].split(' ')[-1]
   ```
2. If the `while` loop exits successfully, the topmost file in the directory will be your file, which you can then modify using `os.rename` (or anything else you like).

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, I think I will go with something like this. Save the preferred file names to a file, then list all the files with their date created after I download all of them, and rename at that time.

Comment: @user1253952 You can actually change at the time of download using that method if it works better. Happy to help

Comment: +1, this is what I did to overcome this problem, is essentially constantly poll the download directory.

Comment: @Arran Ha, nice to hear somebody else does it that way too :)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a little bit strange way: do not download files with the use of Selenium if possible.

I mean get the file URL and use `urllib` library to download the file and save it to disk in a 'manual' way. The issue is that selenium doesn't have a tool to handle Windows dialogs, such as 'save as' dialog. I'm not sure, but I doubt that it can handle any OS dialogs at all, please correct me I'm wrong. :)

Here's a tiny example:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve( "http://www.yourhost.com/yourfile.ext", "your-file-name.ext")
```

The only job for us here is to make sure that we handle all the urllib Exceptions. Please see http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to use selenium (or something similar) as I have to navigate through a few non restful links first.

Comment: I realize this, you can easily use urllib functions in your testcase, can't you?

Comment: I'm not sure, could you give me an example? What I'm trying to do is download ~6000 files (logging in up front, navigating a couple pages, then 6000 times clicking a download and next button). So would I grab the url of the download link and do it with urllib? I don't think it would work because I have to be logged in, and again, the links are non restful, so I think it'd need to have the session variables also. But, I'll try it! And if you have any other suggestions, let me know.

Comment: Well, you can get cookies by calling that:

`cookies = driver.get_cookies()`

You won't be able to use urllib, but urllib2 openers could help (urllib doesn't know how to send cookie headers, and urllib2 does):

`opener = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()) )
opener.addheaders.append( ('Cookies', 'key=val, key2=val2') )`

Also, you can build a Request object and use Request.add_header to add raw header to your HTTP request (please check cookie header format):

`Request.add_header('Cookies', 'key=val,key2=val2')`

Please tell if something unclear.

Comment: why not use selenium to get to the end link, then get the link href using selenium and pass it to urllib to actually retrieve the file?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with code as suggested by the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317609/5446749). Rename the file after each one is downloaded.

```
import os

os.chdir(SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY)
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY))
files = [os.path.join(SAVE_TO_DIRECTORY, f) for f in files]  # add path to each file
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
newest_file = files[-1]
os.rename(newest_file, docName + ".pdf")
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13317457/3) to the question [naming a file when downloading with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317457/naming-a-file-when-downloading-with-selenium-webdriver) by the OP [user1253952](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253952/user1253952) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>