# Automate print/save web page as pdf in chrome - python 3.6

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a script to automatically save read-only pdfs via Chrome's printing functionality to save it as another pdf in the same folder. This removes the 'read-only' feature. However while running the script I am not sure where I can specify my own specific destination folder and the script saves it in the Downloads folder directly.

Full props to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432614/ross-smith-ii for the code below.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
downloadPath = r'mypath\downloadPdf\\'
appState = {
"recentDestinations": [
    {
        "id": "Save as PDF",
        "origin": "local"
    }
],
"selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
"version": 2
}

profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':json.dumps(appState)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile) 
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) 
pdfPath = r'mypath\protected.pdf' 
driver.get(pdfPath) 
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [naming a file when downloading with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317457/naming-a-file-when-downloading-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Sounds good, I'll retract the flag.

Comment: For me, `driver.execute_script('window.print();')` just closes the window, nothing downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I figured out the solution. Just append the following line with the below code:

```
profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':json.dumps(appState),'savefile.default_directory':downloadPath}
```

It's not ideal still as you cannot specify the new file name you want but it works for now.

If anyone has a better solution, please do post it here. Thanks

Comment: replacing this line will automatically download the file

Comment: any idea of how to set a name for this? Im doing it with shutil for now