# How to prevent or manage download while using driver.get in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have some urls, which include xml code, but are not named .xml which I want to open with chrome driver + selenium. Everytime I try Chrome downloads the files.

A download is fine, but I somehow need to name the downloads in a specific way.

The other option would be to prevent the download and than save later or work with the files somehow before I save them somewhere.

How can I name or even better prevent the download and get just the content of any URL called

I use python

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317457/naming-a-file-when-downloading-with-selenium-webdriver)?

Comment: thanks, renaming and using urllib sound more like a workaround to me. If there's no option with selenium itself i will try this.